# How do I solve for x in here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone help me solve this one? All I need to do is to isolate x in the following equation:

$\ e^{-x/t}+e^{-x/z}=1-\frac{2}{e}$

t and z are real numbers, yet unknown.

Thanks!

Comment: Mathematica returns nothing. I'm fairly convinced there is no simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is of the form
$a^x+b^x = c$
which can only
be solved numerically
in general.

Answer to original question:

Since $2/e < 1$
and $e^z > 0$
for all real $z$,
the left side is always positive
and the right side is negative
so there are no solutions.

Comment: Sorry Marty that was a typo. I have corrected it now. Was supposed to be the other way around

Comment: Good point though!

Comment: Would you happen to have a source on that?